# Looking for a clean way to add additional channels of zeros to an NxNxC tensor with an unknown batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So currently I have this code which will pad a `BxNxNxC` tensor to a `BxNxNx(C+P)`tensor, where B is batch size, C is the number of channels, and P is the number of padding channels I want to add:

```
A = <some BxNxNxC tensor>

P = <some calculation>
padding_tensor = keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=[1, 1, P])(tf.zeros_like(A)[:, :, :, 0:1])

# This is the BxNxNx(C+P) tensor
concat = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([A, padding_tensor])
```

The reason I do this in a round about way is because I cannot directly create a `padding_tensor` of the correct size, because it seems impossible to get the batch size to specify the shape.

I want clean way to do this because I am looking at the computation graphs of my Models and this adds a lot of bloat. If it is possible to sort of hide all of these operations into a single computation node I would be happy enough with that but would rather not have to use 3 operations for something as simple as padding.

I also suspect this will be kind of slow, but I don't know enough about tensorflow to really know.

Comment: Since I won't be using this in my code, I don't want to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is my suggestion... I initialize a fake conv2d layer with zeros and make it not trainable, this will produce 0 output

```
batch, H, W, F, C, P = 32, 28, 28, 3, 5, 6

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (batch,H,W,F))

inp = Input((H,W,F))

x_c = Conv2D(C,3, padding='same')(inp) # BxNxNxC
x_p = Conv2D(P,3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='zeros', name='zeros')(inp) # BxNxNxP
concat = Concatenate()([x_c,x_p]) # BxNxNx(C+P)

model = Model(inp, concat)
model.get_layer('zeros').trainable = False # important
model.summary()

# check if zeros
model.predict(X)[:,:,:,-P:].sum() # 0
```

Comment: This could work but this will have the same overhead as a Conv2D operation, right?

Comment: it's a simple multiplication by 0 and I retain that it's faster than UpSampling3D and zero_like

Comment: I suspect a Conv2D operation is slower than UpSampling3D since up sampling doesn't actually involve any arithmetic, just copying of values.

Comment: I suggest u to give a trial ;-)